# dynamic model in MVC

Tags: asp.net, razor, model-view-controller

Is there a possibility of creating dynamic model in MVC in asp.net
like I have a model:

```
public class Head
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string PreferredName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Now in controller I want to create model called `Hmodel` which will only contains

- Title
- FirstName
- Surname

based on some condition. which I will pass to view.

Comment: Look up ViewModels

Comment: what I really want is to have a model whose attributes can be added or removed during runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after long reading found out that asp.net does not support dynamic model till date. hope this will stop people going towards wrong path. if need such functionality one can use viewbag/dictionary or choose other platform and not mvc

Comment: Have you found any solution? My scenario is that I can have 100 plus fields on a form and I need to display fields depending on who is logged in, so for some users I can display 20 fields for others 60 and so on. The business/validation rules can be different for each user as well. Did you try creating one big model and then using dynamic view model?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your model in a different folder you call "Models"
Like:

```
namespace SolutionName.ProjectName.Models
{
    public class Hmodel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In your controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private Hmodel homeModel;

    public HomeController(HomeModel homeModel)
    {
        this.homeModel = homeModel;
    }

    public ViewResult ViewName()
    {
        Hmodel homeModel = new Hmodel();
        homeModel.FirstName = "Jack";
        //set your other attributes
    }
}
```

You could add in the top of your view:

```
@using SolutionName.Projectname.Models
@model Hmodel
```

To use your model:

```
<p>Model.Firstname</p>
```

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is I don't want to send null attribute to views, as my model is pretty big like it have 200 attribute but half of the time only 100 attributes are populated depending on cases and I don't want to send all other 100 attributes with null value. I am trying to cut the bandwidth use of data transfer betn server and clients.